# Grub bypass Ubuntu installation

Tags: ubuntu, grub2

I have a win10 pc and I'm trying to set up a dual boot with Ubuntu using a pen drive with grub. The problem is when I select install Ubuntu from grub menu it has the same effect as if I click to boot Ubuntu directly from my pen drive, so the installation is not initialized but the Ubuntu SO is booted from my pen drive. Am I missing something here? Any tips? 
Thanks!